# Generic/unknown HTTP error when uploading files to a remote form

Tags: c#, forms, unity-game-engine, webrequest

I have an HTML [page](https://mouse-backtracker.herokuapp.com/GESFileUpload.html) with a form for uploading files to SmartFile. Below is the piece of C# code that I am using to upload the files from my game in Unity to this url.

```
WWWForm fileForm = new WWWForm();
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.txt");
fileForm.AddField("file", files[0]);
WWW www = new WWW("https://file.ac/xySSFOicMMk", fileForm);
```

Unfortunately it is leading to the below exception. What is wrong here?

> Connection error while sending analytics... Error:415 Unsupported
>   Media Type UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Survey/Survey.cs:99)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

Update 1:- I changed the 3rd line to `fileForm.AddBinaryData("file", File.ReadAllBytes(files[i]), files[i], "text/plain");`

I'm not getting the error anymore, but still can't see the file getting uploaded, even though `www.isDone` is returning true.

Update 2:- Tried the [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html) API as well, it led to

> Generic/unknown HTTP error (400 response code)

```
List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();           
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(files[0]);
files[0] = files[0].Replace(@".\","");      
formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("file", bytes, files[0], "text/plain"));
StartCoroutine(UploadFile(formData));  
IEnumerator UploadFile(List<IMultipartFormSection> formData)
{       
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://file.ac/xySSFOicMMk", formData);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
```

`UnityWebRequest.Post` does not seem to work either with `WWWForm' or`List` in the Unity version 2017.3.1f1 (64-bit)

Comment: What's the value of `files[0]`?

Comment: I am uploading all the txt files in current directory. I couldn't post the whole code above, it is here - https://pastebin.com/FLLaWT79

Comment: files[i] === C:\Users\vipin\OneDrive\Documents\UnityProjects\PhD Research\AffectiveComputingGames\Bean Man with Affectiva\Bean Man - 4-13-2018-19-44-3-ENGAGEMENT-DUMP.txt

`files[i] === C:\Users\vipin\OneDrive\Documents\UnityProjects\PhD Research\AffectiveComputingGames\Bean Man with Affectiva\Bean Man - 4-13-2018-19-44-3.txt`

Comment: The  problem is on your server side https://file.ac/xySSFOicMMk/ .It doesn't even have a form scrip and gives the 500 Error error. Your other link https://mouse-backtracker.herokuapp.com/GESFileUpload.html is fine and if you view the source, you will see the form code. The bad sad about it is that the action link to the bad url I mentioned https://file.ac/xySSFOicMMk/ . I wasn't able to upload file with my Chrome browser via https://mouse-backtracker.herokuapp.com/GESFileUpload.html so you can't do via code too. Fix it and make sure you can upload code from browser then try via code

Comment: the url throws 500 error, but you can actually upload the file using that link despite 500 error. I have done multiple uploads using it, so it is working fine. I got the test.png that you uploaded using the link - https://file.ac/sU1paNXY4do/

Comment: @Programmer I fixed it just for the sake of it. now you will be redirected to google after successful file upload.

Comment: Ok. I am more willing to help but it there a way to know if it is successful or not. The url is returning a html file. I am using a text file for now. The correct way to make it show if it is successful or not is to use json or simple output error or ok. This will make it easier to troubleshoot than outputting long html data

Comment: Thankyou so much. `www.isHttpError` and  `www.error` should be helpful

Comment: I see that you just uploaded sendtext.txt using the link

Comment: I used `www.isHttpError` can now see the error. Please delete the sendtext.txt text. Let me know when you do so.

Comment: yes, I deleted the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169007/discussion-between-vipin8169-and-programmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the `HttpWebRequest` with the solution found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df031020-8c56-464b-8c93-41e6ccb5d38c/c-windowsforms-send-post-request-including-a-file?forum=csharpgeneral) alongwith [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/50013/httpwebrequestgetrequeststream-https-certificate-e.html) to fix the certificate error in Unity and finally had some peace of mind. Entire solution is posted here - https://pastebin.com/wNQ46s0H

Seems like in order for WWWForm to work, you need to have both the binary and non-binary data in your form - [HttpWebRequest post paramaters for AWS file upload request, leading to 400 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848292/httpwebrequest-post-paramaters-for-aws-file-upload-request-leading-to-400-error/49849628#49849628)