# HttpWebRequest post paramaters for AWS file upload request, leading to 400 error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, httpwebrequest

I am trying to upload files from my Unity game to my AWS account. The form for doing this can be found here. Earlier I was using `FILEUPLOAD_BASE_URL` to be "https://file.ac/xySSFOicMMk/" which doesn't require a key to upload the file (link [here](https://mouse-backtracker.herokuapp.com/GESFileUpload.html)). However, the AWS file upload require a key param in the form whose value can be "/${filename}". I specified the value as `sb.Append("key: AffectivaLogs/${filename}");` as shows below, but the request is throwing a 400 error. Is this the correct way to specify the key as a post request parameter?

```
private string FILEUPLOAD_BASE_URL = "http://gameexperiencesurvey.s3.amazonaws.com/";
public void uploadToDrive()
{    
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback;
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FILEUPLOAD_BASE_URL);
        webrequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        webrequest.Method = "POST";
        // Build up the post message header  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("--");
        sb.Append(boundary);
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("key: AffectivaLogs/${filename}"); // is this how it should be?
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
        sb.Append("file"); // file form name
        sb.Append("\"; filename=\"");
        sb.Append(Path.GetFileName(files[i]));
        sb.Append("\"");
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("Content-Type: ");
        sb.Append("text/plain");
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        sb.Append("\r\n");

        string postHeader = sb.ToString();
        byte[] postHeaderBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postHeader);

        // Build the trailing boundary string as a byte array  
        // ensuring the boundary appears on a line by itself  
        byte[] boundaryBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(files[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        long length = postHeaderBytes.Length + fileStream.Length + boundaryBytes.Length;
        webrequest.ContentLength = length;

        Stream requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();

        // Write out our post header  
        requestStream.Write(postHeaderBytes, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length);

        // Write out the file contents  
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)fileStream.Length))];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        // Write out the trailing boundary  
        requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse();
            Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error occured .... " + e.Message);
        }        
    }
}

public bool MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(System.Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    bool isOk = true;
    // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.ChainStatus.Length; i++)
        {
            if (chain.ChainStatus[i].Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown)
            {
                chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
                chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
                chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;
                bool chainIsValid = chain.Build((X509Certificate2)certificate);
                if (!chainIsValid)
                {
                    isOk = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isOk;
}
```

Error is as follows:
[image]

Comment: There is an official amazon-s3 Unity plugin for this. Use that instead of rewriting the whole API.

Comment: oh .wow. didn't know

Comment: it is a mobile sdk, i hope it works on desktop too

Comment: Just for a heads up I don't think that will work on desktop. Even Google's firebase does not work on desktop. They only care about mobile devices.

Comment: :( then i cant use it. is there any way to make the above thing work?

Comment: Well, it clearly states that Applications written with the AWS SDK for Unity can run on iOS or Android devices.

Comment: I haven't used AWS before. Maybe you should look on their site and see. I think it requires many steps. You need to generate a key or something like that then use that key to make the request. This was before and I don't know if that change. You may want to Google this

Comment: Yes, I read on their site and I am able to upload the files to my AWS using this html page - https://mouse-backtracker.herokuapp.com/AWS_GESupload.html

Comment: If you can do it with that page, you might be able to with code. Why don't you try to with the url you just posted instead of the current one in your question?

Comment: The html page contains the form with this action -http://gameexperiencesurvey.s3.amazonaws.com/ and this is the url i need to submit the form to

Comment: Solved it using WWWForm which was not working yesterday. apparently WWWform needs to have both binary and non-binary data in order for the request to work, totally strange.

Comment: Indeed strange but if you solved it, why not share your solution as answer? I think it will help others in the future.

Comment: Yes, sure. let me just push it to git and then I will post the code here. this is so strange

Comment: Thanks for upvoting @Programmer, seems like you are lucky for me :P

Comment: I upvote what I think will be helpful to people and you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I was trying to use WWWForm and WWW to upload file and I had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835903/generic-unknown-http-error-when-uploading-files-to-a-remote-form?noredirect=1#comment86691280_49835903) where adding the binary data to WWWform was not working. Seems like in order for WWWForm to work, you need to have both the binary and non-binary data in your form. Thus, the following solution worked.

```
public void uploadToAWS()
{
    fileNameList = "";
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        WWWForm AWSform = new WWWForm();
        AWSform.AddField("key", "AffectivaLogs/${filename}");
        AWSform.AddBinaryData("file", File.ReadAllBytes(files[i]), files[i], "text/plain");
        StartCoroutine(Post(FILEUPLOAD_BASE_URL, AWSform));
        fileNameList += files[i].Replace(@".\", "") + "  ||  ";
    }
} 
IEnumerator Post(string url, WWWForm form)
{               
    WWW www = new WWW(url, form);
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        //Matrix4x4 wait time is 20s
        if (elapsedTime >= 20f)
        {
            break;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
    if (!www.isDone || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Connection error while sending analytics... Error:" + www.error);
        // Error handling here.
        yield break;
    }

    if (www.isDone)
    {            
        Debug.Log("Data Sent successfully.");
        yield break;
    }        
}
```